# Recover branch in remote GitLab Repository

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

Accidentally couple of branches deleted in our remote GitLab repository. Locally also copy not available. Have cloned freshly and tried below reflog commands, but it is not showing deleted branch related details. Is there way to restore(recover) them back?

```
git reflog show --all
git reflog --no-abbrev
```

Comment: Each branches have been created by someone, you should have it on local of some users

Comment: Unfortunately locally also data not available.